# Backbone.js and models that changed on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

We are using Backbone.js to build client-side UI that manipulates models shared by multiple users. It is fairly straight-forward to setup Backbone.js to fetch data from server, and sync changes to server. However, what is the best practice for updating a model that has changed from the server?

1) Is it that we have to regularly sync with the server to update the model? If so, is there an existing way in Backbone.js to do this automatically?

Or,

2) Is there a Javascript library and RoR gem that work well with Backbone.js, that uses the whole reverse HTTP pattern to have server updates clients about changes other users have made?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, the PusherApp is popular to send updates from server to client. Found this game, which is a pretty fun way to visualize what's happening -- it's using Backbone.js. Also: socket.io has some mindshare.

[image: Pusher'ed]

Credit and more game fun: http://logicalfriday.com/2011/09/19/ace-invaders/

Answer (score 0):

I like push stream pattern to do that.

nginx server has a module for work with it: https://github.com/wandenberg/nginx-push-stream-module

But you can use either [websocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

Facebook use websocket and send a command for their API update the model that has a update to be done. Or you can send an javascript command for your client and eval in the client-side (not the best way, but lite faster then correct way).

Hope help solve your problem. Other way is to check with setInterval or some refresh event.